# Grails project in eclipse under git won't run from the grails run-app command

Tags: eclipse, git, grails

I have a grails project under Eclipse that runs fine from the right click -> run as -> grails run-app option. However, when I move the project under git control, using the Eclipse Egit plugin, it won't run as such anymore. Grails complains that the project in the directory doesn't appear to be a grails application. I think what is going on here is that when I place the project under git control using Egit, git moves it under its own repository that it makes you create and the project isn't in the Eclipse workspace anymore, I confirmed this by navigation under windows to my Eclipse project workspace directory. Instead, git just leaves a symbolic link or something to the project in the eclipse workspace, which is why the project continues to show up in the project workspace in eclipse. Since after moving it under git, I can't get it to run using the right click -> run as -> grails run-app on the project followed by "grails run-app", what I do is open up a command prompt and navigate to the directory where the project really is (under git's repository and then into the project directory) and then type "grails run-app" and it runs fine. Anyway to solve this so that I can continue to run from the project right click menu even after the project is under git control? That way I can have version control as well as preserve my right-click to run the project option? Fyi, I am just doing local git no github.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so upon research I found out that Grails has it own built in versioning system. I haven't looked into it further yet but I thought I would throw this answer up in case someone else is also running into the same issue. So, I might not need to use git with grails because of its own versioning system. This is discussed in the Grails documentation.